# What is the best way to perform multithreaded interruptible continuous computations?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm developing a program which can performs very long computations and must be interrupted (Travelling Salesman Problem). To gain performance, I'd like to use as many threads as logical cores on the running machine.

My problem is that I'm not sure that the way I'm dealing with is the best. Each thread must return the best computed solution until a timeout. My parallel code have arround 100 lines of code so I don't feel that checking whether the thread is interrupted several times in the thread's main loop is elegant.

For the moment, to achieve this, I was thinking something like that:

```
int countThreads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
List<Solution> solutions = new ArrayList<Solution>(countThreads);
final ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(countThreads + 1);

//Thread that cancel all the other one after the timeout
executor.schedule(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        executor.shutdownNow();
    }
}, timeMax, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

//Threads that compute
for(int i = 0; i < countThreads; i++) {
    Solution currentSolution = new Solution();
    solutions.add(currentSolution);

    ThreadedSolutionFinder solutionFinder =
            new ThreadedSolutionFinder(seed, instance, currentSolution);
        executor.submit(solutionFinder);
}

// The main thread waits
try {
    executor.awaitTermination(timeMax, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
System.out.println("All tasks terminated");

//Iterate over all the found solutions and find the best
//...
```

What we do here, is that the main thread, instanciate one solution per thread and give it as argument to the threads's constructors. The run() method of these threads, fill the given solution.

But there are many issues, for example a thread after the shutdownNow() command, can continue its execution until it checks Thread.interrupted() and so awaitTermination() in the main thread does not last enough. This implies concurrency access when I iterate over all the solutions to find the best.

I'm not convinced by this design. Do some of you have some ideas?

Comment: I'm not convinced by it either. Why not just gather the futures returned by `executor.submit(...)`, and cancel them if they take longer than X to complete?

Comment: It's because each thread must return a solution, even if it is interrupted. The computations can take several minutes and the program should be able to be interrupted after 2 seconds. In fact, each thread generate a random solution (it is fast) but, then it optimizes the solution and this step is very very slow.

Comment: What result can you return if it is interrupted?

Comment: When it is interrupted, the solution that is being optimized must be returned. It's like some 3D renderer that render without stopping. They can be interrupted at anytime. But the better you let them compute, the better is the result.

Comment: My answer will allow you to do this just fine, since you're injecting the `Solution` instance (into which, I am assuming, you populate the solution)

Answer (score 0):

Put the `Future` instances returned by `ExecutorService.submit` into a list:

```
List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < countThreads; ++i) {
  ThreadedSolutionFinder solutionFinder = ...
  futures.add(executor.submit(solutionFinder));
}
```

Then work out when you want to complete by:

```
long endTime = System.nanoTime() + TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(timeMax);
```

And iterate through the futures, waiting for an appropriate amount of time that would take you up to the end time; cancel the task if it hasn't completed by then:

```
for (Future<?> future : futures) {
  if (!future.isDone()) {
    long timeout = endTime - System.nanoTime();
    if (timeout >= 0) {
      try {
        future.get(timeout, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
      } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        // Handle it.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, cancel everything (this has no effect on completed `Future`s):

```
for (Future<?> future : futures) {
  future.cancel(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're either going to need to add code to check each thread for interrupt or divide your algorithm into smaller pieces and run those. If your timeout is a soft limit and the work that you do is small and fairly regular then doing the second option may be viable.

Imagining a naive implementation of TSP you could have each of your runnables step and find the next closest city for each of the current solutions:

```
CompletionService<PartialSolution> comp = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(executor);

// Submit initial runners
comp.submit(new PartialSolutionTask());
...

long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
// Only wait 30 total seconds
final long end = current + TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(30);

while (current < end) {
    Future<PartialSolution> f = comp.poll(end - current, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    if (f == null) {
        // Timeout
        break;
    }

    // Submit a new task using the results of the previous task
    comp.submit(new PartialSolutionTask(f.get()));

    current = System.currentTimeMillis();

}
// Still should have the same number of running tasks so wait for them to finish by calling comp.poll() N times
```

Unfortunately you're going to go over the time limit some waiting for those final runs to finish but if their run time is small enough it should be workable.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I've found another solution (neither worse or better than yours I think):

```
public Solution executeThreads() {
    List<Solution> solutions = new ArrayList<Solution>(countThreads);
    List<Callable<Object>> threads = new ArrayList<Callable<Object>>(countThreads);
    final ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(countThreads + 1);

    //Thread that cancel all the other one after the timeout
    executor.schedule(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            executor.shutdownNow();
        }
    }, timeMax, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    //Threads that compute
    for(int i = 0; i < countThreads; i++) {
        Solution currentSolution = new Solution();
        solutions.add(currentSolution);

        ThreadedSolutionFinder solutionFinder =
                new ThreadedSolutionFinder(i, instance, currentSolution);

        threads.add(Executors.callable(solutionFinder));
    }

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    /* Execute and then wait that all threads have finished */
    try {
        executor.invokeAll(threads);

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("All tasks terminated in " + time / 1000.f + "s");

    //Iterate over all the found solutions
    //...
```

In ThreadedSolutionFinder:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    thread = Thread.currentThread();
    solution.setOF(Double.MAX_VALUE); //No solution so it has the higher cost

    do {
        Solution randomSolution = generateRandomSolution();
        Solution localSearchSol = localSearch(randomSolution);
        System.out.println("[Worker " + workerId +
                "] " + randomSolution.getOF() + "\t-> " + localSearchSol.getOF());

        if(localSearchSol.getOF() < solution.getOF()) {
            //Copy the elements because the solution reference must not change
            solution.clear();
            solution.addAll(localSearchSol);
            solution.setOF(localSearchSol.getOF());
        }

    } while(!thread.isInterrupted());
}

private Solution generateRandomSolution() {
    Solution solution = new Solution();

    /* We add all the city (index) to the solution,
     * no more things are required. TSPCostCalculator
     * do the trick */
    for(int i = 0; i < instance.getN(); i++) {
        solution.add(i);
    }

    //Randomize the solution indices (cities)
    Collections.shuffle(solution, ThreadLocalRandom.current());

    //Compute the efficiency of the solution
    solution.setOF(TSPCostCalculator.calcOF(instance, solution));

    return solution;
}

/* Return the best solution among many changed solution
 * (local search algorithm)
 * @param generatedSolution The solution to begin with
 * @return the best solution found with the algorithm,
 * null if no better solution
 */
private Solution localSearch(Solution solution) {
    boolean continueExploration = true;
    Solution bestSolution = solution;

    while(continueExploration && !thread.isInterrupted())
    {
        Solution swapSolution;

        swapSolution = exploreNeighborhood(bestSolution);
        //TODO: Solve this, computeSwapCost is inaccurate
        if((float)swapSolution.getOF() < (float)bestSolution.getOF())
            bestSolution = swapSolution;
        else
            continueExploration = false;
    }

    return bestSolution;
}

/* Return the best solution among many changed solution
 * (local search algorithm)
 * @param generatedSolution The solution to begin with
 * @return the best solution found with the algorithm
 */
private Solution exploreNeighborhood(Solution solution) {
    Solution bestSolution = solution;
    Solution swapSolution = solution.clone();

    for(int i = 0; i < solution.size() && !thread.isInterrupted(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < solution.size() && !thread.isInterrupted(); j++)
        {
            double costBefore = swapSolution.getOF();

            double relativeCostBefore = computeSwapCost(swapSolution, i, j);
                swapSolution.swap(i, j);
                double relativeCostAfter = computeSwapCost(swapSolution, i,     j);
                double diffCost = relativeCostBefore - relativeCostAfter;

                swapSolution.setOF(costBefore - diffCost);

                if(swapSolution.getOF() < bestSolution.getOF()) 
                    bestSolution = swapSolution.clone();
            }
        }

        return bestSolution;
    }
}
```

On big instances of cities (e.g. 10k), the program stop immediately. The only issue (maybe not related to the design we were speaking about) is that even on 4 physical cores, 2 or 3 threads give the best TSP solution. The fact to have more than 2 or 3, give worse solutions among all the threads (very strange, I can't explain since there is no synchronization).